# How to display a Flash message that's sent from the frontend in Flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to send an error message from the frontend to eventually display it as a flash message on the same page. Seems like the page isn't being re-rendered and the message isn't being displayed.
The page template - "page.html":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>
      Alert
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
      {% for category, message in messages %}
      {% set color = "red" if category == "error" else "green" %}
        <span style="color: '{{color}}'">{{message}}</span>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}

    <button id="post-btn">post</button>
    
    <!-- JS Global Compulsory -->
    <script src="/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/vendor/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      $('#post-btn').on("click", async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        await fetch(
          '/endpoint',
          {
            method: "POST", 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({error: 'This is an error message'})
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The view function that gets the POST request looks like:

```py
@app.route("/endpoint", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def endpoint():
    if request.method == "POST":
        request_body = request.json

        if "error" in request_body:
            flash(request_body["error"], category="danger")
            return redirect(url_for("endpoint"))

    return render_template("page.html")
```

Using the debugger, I checked the `session["_flashes"]` right before `return render_template("page.html")` and I could see the messages there.

Comment: _"The flashing system basically makes it possible to record a message at the end of a request and access it next request and only next request."_  It is implemented with a cookie. I'm not a HTTP protocol expert to say it is not possible, but if it is possible, you need to make a plan how this cookie is set and received back to be rendered and then write code to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I can store the error message in the flask session object and look for
this error message each time I'm loading the page.
So the javescript in the `page.html` template will look like:

```html
<script>
  $('#post-btn').on("click", async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    const response = await fetch(
      '/endpoint',
      {
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({error: 'This is an error message'})
      }
    );
    window.location.href = "/endpoint";
  });
</script>
```

And the `endpoint` view function like:

```py
@app.route("/endpoint", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def endpoint():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session["error_message"] = request.json.get("error")
        return {}

    alert = session.pop("error_message", None)
    if alert:
        flash(alert, category="danger")

    return render_template("page.html")
```